# How do I write something at the end of the slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer, spacing, positioning

I have an image, I want to write its source in a very small font size on the last possible line of the slide, ignoring the available space after image

```
\section{SCS}
\subsection{SCS}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Simple Client-Server}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{scs}
  \end{center}
  source of image :write this text at the bottom of the slide (not footnote)
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a common problem in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), with the typical solution being given by a fixed-height `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\section{SCS}
\subsection{SCS}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Simple Client-Server}
  \begin{minipage}[t][.8\textheight]{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \rule{150pt}{100pt}%\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{scs}
    \end{center}
    
    \vfill
    
    source of image :write this text at the bottom of the slide (not footnote)
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, the `frame` body is set in a box (or `minipage`) of (seemingly arbitrary) height equivalent to `.8\textheight`. This fixed height allows the use of `\vfill` to push content to the bottom.

Answer (score 41):

The following solution works works without employing a minipage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\begin{document}
\section{SCS}
\subsection{SCS}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Simple Client-Server}
  \bigskip
  \rule{150pt}{100pt}%\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{scs}
  \btVFill

  source of image :write this text at the bottom of the slide (not footnote)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also equally distribute the available space by employing the `\btVFill` command multiple times; the bottom line can be lifted a bit by adding some vertical space (such as `\smallskip`) after it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\begin{document}
\section{SCS}
\subsection{SCS}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Simple Client-Server}
  \bigskip
  \rule{150pt}{100pt}%\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{scs}
  \btVFill
  a comment in the middle
  \btVFill

  source of image :write this text at the bottom of the slide (not footnote)
  \smallskip
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the `btVFill` command?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: `\vskip0pt plus 1filll` is TeX syntax to insert a stretchable vertical skip with a minimum of 0pt, but stretchable to "infinite value". So TeX will stretch the vertical skip as much as possible (depending on the following content), which here gives the intended result to skip to the bottom of the slide. The details of stretchable skips are pretty well explained in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64759/3751) from JLDiaz.

Comment: This works great to produce a footer text! However, it appears first when all `\pause` statements in the frame have been processed, so only at the last slide of the frame. How do I make this text visible on _all_ slides of the frame?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever This is difficult using just `\pause`. In that case you should use `\onslide<1->{bottom text}` and replace all `\pause` commands with the correct `\onslide` commands.