# Change direction of a textbox, taking up space from above instead from below

Tags: beamer, pdftex, boxes, text-manipulation

I am designing a custom theme for my LaTeX presentations. This is my title page:[image: It is okay this way]

Now when I have a longer title, this happens:

[image: This happens]

Here's my code (according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch)):

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{pure}[1][]
{ 
   \vskip5.5cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm]{rule}
      \textcolor{black!70}{\rule{8cm}{.2mm}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.2cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{title page header}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.75cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
     \vskip0.2cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
}
```

What can I do? I do not want to adjust my `\vskip` in the style definition every time. Can I tell LaTeX to invert the direction so that my textbox grows to the top instead of pushing everything to the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution myself! [This question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54180/how-do-i-write-something-at-the-end-of-the-slide-in-beamer) is about the same problem in its core. This is how you can achieve what I was looking for:

```
\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}
% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{pure}[1][]{
\btVFill
% \vskip5.5cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm]{rule}
        \textcolor{black!70}{\rule{8cm}{.2mm}}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.2cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{title page header}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.75cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip0.2cm
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=11cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip0.75cm
    % \vfill
}
```

Note that I commented out `\vskip5.5cm`, to allow my text to go to the top, and `\vfill`, which is unnecessary now, as there should not be any free space due to the new command `\btVFill`.