# beamer title with \hfill

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I include citations in the titles of slides and I would like the citations to be right justified (fully) while the title itself is left justified. I used

```
<title-text> \hfill <\cite{}>
```

but this does not push the citation to make it right-justified; it simply moves the citation a bit to the right as shown in the following figure. Is there any way to make the citation right-justified?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the last answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54180/how-do-i-write-something-at-the-end-of-the-slide-in-beamer where @Daniel uses `\vskip0pt plus 1filll`. Perhaps it will work for you if you change `\vskip0pt` to `\hskip0pt` and then use the entire bit instead of `\hfill`. (I haven't tried it.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked beautifully. I had searched but totally missed that answer. Just for completeness, here is my definition: \newcommand{\myhfill}{\hskip0pt plus 1filll} and \myhfill is used instead of \hfill in my original code.

Answer (score 6):

Following the suggestion at [How do I write something at the end of the slide in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54180/how-do-i-write-something-at-the-end-of-the-slide-in-beamer) as suggested by 3cat I defined

```
\newcommand{\myhfill}{\hskip0pt plus 1filll}
```

and used `\myhfill` instead of `\hfill` and it works like a charm. Putting this as an answer since otherwise I cannot close the question.

Comment: I would prefer the name `\hfilll`.

Comment: Of course you can choose any name you wish.