# Tabular at bottom of beamer slide (above footline)

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I would like to put content at the bottom of some slide, possibly containing environment such as `tabular`, in a manner similar to footnotes but without footnote marks.
My current attempt is the following, with `vfill` being *not enough*.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Duke says}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item It don't mean a thing
  \end{itemize}
\vfill{\footnotesize%
\hrule\vspace{.2em}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    If it ain't got & that swing.\\
  \end{tabular}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To this frames add option `[b]`. This should help.

Comment: @Zarko With the `[b]` option, all the content is move downwards which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: for that you ask in your question ... Than you actually need a footnote. Why then you not use it?

Comment: @Zarko: I would like to avoid the footnote marks and it seems that tabular environment are a problem in footnotes.

Comment: If you not use footnotes in your presentation, than you can add to preamble `\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{}\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{~}` and put your table (tabular) into `\footnote{<whatever>\\}`.

Comment: @Zarko: there are 2 problems with that approach. 1) There is a leading dot in the footnote. 2) Tabular content appears inline, not as a table.

Comment: In my test I didn't observe this.  Better solution is proposed in Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The following defines and uses a `\btVFill` command that pushes the content really to the bottom of the slide. See also [How do I write something at the end of the slide in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54180/how-do-i-write-something-at-the-end-of-the-slide-in-beamer/54237#54237)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Duke says}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item It don't mean a thing
  \end{itemize}
\btVFill
{\footnotesize%
\hrule\vspace{.2em}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    If it ain't got & that swing.\\
  \end{tabular}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\btVFill` command inserts an infinitely stretchable vertical fill, which has the side effect that the content above it is also pushed to the top. To prevent this, one can just "stack" several `\btVFill`. In this case TeX will distribute the vertical space equally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Duke says}
\btVFill
  \begin{itemize}
  \item It don't mean a thing
  \end{itemize}
\btVFill
{\footnotesize%
\hrule\vspace{.2em}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    If it ain't got & that swing.\\
  \end{tabular}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need a `\btVfill` also at the start

Comment: @egreg: Sure, if you want the other content to be vertically centered.